# I want to access the files in htdocs on my smartphone inside the same network

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache, networking

I am developing in php and I have mysql as backend, on a windows 7 machine. I have installed *xampp* server and i'm using *apache 2.4* as the web server. I have a mtnl router and all my devices are connected to it. I want to access everything which is present in the htdocs folder on my android smartphone. I saw some posts about editing `httpd.conf` file but no use. Please specify what to edit in the conf file.

Thanks in advance!

my `ip-config o/p` is:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
       Link-local IPv6 Address: fe80::853e:7ced:1b5e:91cc%12
       IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.103
       Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
       Default Gateway:192.168.1.1
```

my httpd.conf file ka edits looks like this:

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 :: 192.168.1
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168.1
```

```
**SOLUTION FOUND:**
```

As #BenH said we have to edit the httpd.conf as he's shown

Goto firewall and add apache server to the exception list

to setup a static ip go to network and sharing and open adapter settings,

select current connected adapter rightclick and click on the properties

click on ipv4 properties click on the use the following ip address

ur ip address: 192.168.1.xyz

xyz can be anything from 02 to 255

subnet mask:255.255.255.0

default gateway: 192.168.1.1

for mtnl preferred dns server in mumbai is :59.185.0.23

alt:203.94.227.70
click ok

restart the apache

Thank u everyone especially BenH for helping me out :)

Comment: Have both devices an IP with the same subnet mask and the same ip range? Firewall deactivated? Is there a proxy configured on the phone or some special routes?

Comment: ya the firewall is off they are at my home under the same router
there is no proxy or any special routes would u like to view my httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set static IP to each devices on your local network. Then you'll have to configure apache to allow connection from all and not only from 127.0.0.1, it should be in httpd.conf :

```
AllowOverride All
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
```

Comment: sir my httpd.conf file looks like this:

    #

    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 127.0.0.1 :: 192.168.1
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
 Allow from 192.168.1
</Directory>

Comment: ill try to give static ip to my laptop on the local net

Comment: i have allocated my laptop 192.168.1.20 static ip
i've made these changes and i restarted apache from services.msrc do i need to restart my laptop? its still not loading on my smartphone

Comment: try to ping your laptop from your android if you can access terminal. you only have to restart apache.

Comment: thank u so much bro!!!! :) it worked !! its working like butter!!! the firewall is off and yes i only had to restart the apache.. it took me so long but it was a super silly error,I was using OPERA MINI on my smartphone all this while...:/ i changed browser to chrome and it worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off your firewall.

Comment: no use :( still its giving network error on my phone

Comment: Are you typing your host name or ip?

Comment: i was typing my local netword ip address 192.168.1.103